# Need to run some code (insert into DB) before minitest route testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rails-routing

Due to some requirement (by the product owner) I have to stray from the golden path and overwrite a resource route for some urls that match a constraint.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  CATEGORY_SLUGS = Regexp.new(Category.all.collect(&:slug).join('|'))
  get '/posts/:category', to: 'posts#index', as: :category_posts, constraints: { category: CATEGORY_SLUGS }
  resources :posts
end
```

and my test:

```
require 'test_helper'
class PotsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # routes
  test "/posts/:category" do
    Fabricate(:category, slug: 'rails')

    assert_recognizes({controller: 'posts', action: 'index', category: 'rails' }, 'posts/rails')
  end
```

The test obviously fails because the routes are drawn long before the test starts and the `Category` doesn't exist yet at that point.

Is there any good alternative to the `CATEGORY_SLUGS` or anything in the test do draw the routes later?

Comment: Why not choose the more RESTful approach: `/categories/:slug/posts`? That would solve all of your problems. If that's not possible, perhaps you can introduce a constraint that only matches non-integer parameters, so you don't need to compare with all the slugs from the database.

Comment: yes it would, but the product owner wants different urls. matching non-integer params isn't an option either because the posts have slugs as well and some categories start with numbers.

Comment: I tried turning the constraint into a class, but that just moved the problem around.

Comment: Perhaps you can convince the product owner to go for the route `/posts/for/:category`. It would make *your* life a lot easier.

Comment: it's not an option.

Comment: I would definitely hardcode `CATEGORY_SLUGS`. I consider it a very bad practice to touch the database during app configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your test setup with the `Fabricate` call in this case, you can request that Rails reloads its routes with:

```
Rails.application.reload_routes!
```

This should ensure that the dynamic routes are generated ahead of your `assert_recognizes` call.

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed allow me to test the route.

Comment: Awesome. And with this, I've just become a Stack Overflow moderator (!) https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8doas52ghhrj7f/Screenshot%202017-07-16%2021.44.06.png?dl=0

Comment: :) Just wait till you somehow get your first golden badge.

Answer (score 1):

This approach (cunstructing a constraint in routing configuration using data from an ActiveRecord model) has serious drawbacks. Not only that it's almost impossible to test it properly, but you also have to restart the application whenever categories change, in order to re-build the constraint.

I suggest moving the logic to the controller action. You will pay a small performance price for it (an additional database query when rendering a Post), but it's definitely worth it. It can be mitigated by introducing a query cache for Categories if necessary.

Routing:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
end
```

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    category = Category.find_by_slug params[:id]
    if category
      # ... render a Category

      return
    end

    post = Post.find_by_slug params[:id]
    # ... render a Post
  end
```